# WPF Combobox with SelectedValue is behaving weird

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, selected

I have a `ComboBox` that contains a certain number of years. However, i have trouble with the item, that should be selected.

XAML

```
 <ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="90" Height="10" Width="80" ItemsSource="{Binding accy}"  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayMember" SelectedValuePath="ValuePath" SelectedValue="{Binding Accy_selected}"/>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        this.DataContext = new Test();}
```

Test.cs

```
class Test
{
    public ObservableCollection<ComboYear> accy { get; set; }
    private string _accy_selected = "";

    public Test()
    {
        int min = 1940;
        int max = 2040;
        accy = new ObservableCollection<ComboYear>();                                    
            for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
            {
                accy.Add(new ComboYear { DisplayMember = Convert.ToString(i), ValuePath = Convert.ToString(i) });
            }
            Accy_selected = Convert.ToString(max);                     
    }

        public class ComboYear
        {
            public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
            public string ValuePath { get; set; }
        }       

    public string Accy_selected
    {
        get { return _accy_selected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _accy_selected)
            {
                _accy_selected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Accy_selected");
            }

        }
    }
```

The `ComboBox` gets filled, but no item is selected. The strange part about this is if i change this line

```
Accy_selected = Convert.ToString(max);
```

to this it's working. It's working for every year in the `ComboBox`. Am i too stupid to convert an `int` into a `string`?

```
Accy_selected = "2039";
```

I have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

`max` (`2040`) is not included in the `ComboBox`, is it? You are iterating as long as the counter variable `i` is *less than* `max`:

```
for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
```

If you change the condition to `i <= max`, the value "2040" should be included and selected when you set the `Accy_selected` property like this:

```
Accy_selected = Convert.ToString(max);
```